# Load images from Html.ImageGetter to an ImageView

Tags: android, html, imageview

I need to load my images that my Html.ImageGetter gets from a text containing some HTML code into ImageViews.

Those ImageViews need to be EXACTLY where their HTML-counterpart is. i.e:

```
blablablabla <img src='link.to.img' /> blablablabla
```

So, the ImageView needs to be where the `<img />`thing is:

```
blablablabla ImageView blablablabla
```

I put all of the HTML text into a TextView: `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text, imageGetter, null));`

I tried so many options, but I can't figure it out. Is there a simple and fast way to do this, instead of splitting the text every `<img>` tag?

Hope I've explained well my question.

Comment: you need to implement `Html.ImageGetter#getDrawable(String source)` method

Comment: @pskink: Yes, I know, but it will only set the image in an HTML-unclickable "ImageView". What I need is to get the same result, but with an Android ImageView.

Comment: There is nowhere an ImageView in your code. Instead you are using a TextView.

Comment: @greenapps: That's because I'm willing to change that. The ImageViews will be added dinamically when and where there will be an `<img>` tag.